# Saving a reference to a localized filehandle. How does it work?

Tags: perl

This question is based on the observed behavior of [`patch`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/BDFOY/PerlPowerTools-1.017/bin/patch) running with a certain version of `perl`. When running a command like:

```
$ patch -N -p0 -u -b .bak < my.patch
```

I occasionally got output like:

```
print() on unopened filehandle NULL at patch line 715, <IN> line 12330.
```

When looking into the [code](https://metacpan.org/source/BDFOY/PerlPowerTools-1.017/bin/patch#L432), I see that the NULL filehandle is localized and saved in the object hash:

```
sub new {
    # ....
    local *NULL;
    tie *NULL, 'Dev::Null';
    $self->{o_fh} = \*NULL;     # output filehandle
    # ....
}
```

Since this behavior (the output of the message `print() on unopened filehandle NULL`) only occured for certain versions of `perl` and (maybe certain version of the `patch` program) I wondered if this is a bug? To me it looks like one should not localize `NULL` since we are saving a reference to it and the value of reference (`*NULL`) will be restored to its previous value when returning from `new()`.

Here is a minimal example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
my $p = Patch->new();
$p->apply();

package Patch;

sub new {
    my ( $class ) = @_;
    my $self = bless {}, $class;

    local *NULL;
    tie *NULL, 'Dev::Null';
    $self->{null} = \*NULL;
    local *OUT;
    my $out = 'out.txt';
    open OUT, ">$out" or die "Couldn't open '$out': $!\n";
    $self->{out} = \*OUT;
    return $self;
}

sub apply {
    my ( $self ) = @_;    
    my $null = $self->{null};
    say $null "This should be discarded..";
    my $out = $self->{out};
    say $out "This is output to the file..";
}

package Dev::Null;
sub TIEHANDLE { bless \my $null }
sub PRINT {}
sub PRINTF {}
sub WRITE {}
sub READLINE {''}
sub READ {''}
sub GETC {''}
```

The output when I run this is:

```
say() on unopened filehandle NULL at ./p.pl line 34.
say() on unopened filehandle OUT at ./p.pl line 36.
```

Comment: Re "*only occured for certain versions of perl*", Your program warns on [all versions](https://pastebin.com/rvLg7Z3S) of Perl. (Also on 5.8 if `say` is replaced with `print`.)

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for testing. Then it must be related to the version of `patch` I used. I originally started with trying to install [`Alien::wxWidgets`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::wxWidgets) which had a [packaged version](https://st.aticpan.org/source/MDOOTSON/Alien-wxWidgets-0.69/inc/bin/patch) of `patch` with version 0.25, later I tried to install [version 0.27](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/BDFOY/PerlPowerTools-1.017/bin/patch) and observed differences in the behavior though both localizes `*NULL` so it is strange

Comment: The linked code uses `*NULL` and `*OUT`, not `\*NULL` and `\*OUT` like your program. This [doesn't warn](https://pastebin.com/nuHeL7C3) and does works.

Comment: As far [as I can see](https://metacpan.org/source/BDFOY/PerlPowerTools-1.017/bin/patch#L437) (see line 437) is uses `\*NULL` not `*NULL`

Comment: woops. Ok, let me rephrase: `local *FH; $self->{fh} = *FH;` works (like `OUT` in the linked code), and `local *FH; $self->{fh} = \*FH;`  doesn't work and warns (like `NULL` in the linked code). Of course, since the goal of using `NULL` is to sink the data, using a non-handle ends up working if you disregard the warning.

Comment: Replace `\*OUT` with `*OUT`, then add `use Devel::Peek; Dump(*OUT); Dump($out); Dump(*{$out}{IO});` in `apply`. Pay attention to `IO` for the globs, and `IFP`/`OFP` for the IOs. Same for `NULL`. Also pay attention to the `STASH` (the tied package) under the `tiedscalar` MAGIC for the `NULL` IO

Comment: Now that I've done my research, what is your question? There isn't one in the post itself, and the one in the title is rather vague

Comment: Thanks, I think the question has been answered yes: It is indeed a bug. It should use `*NULL` and not `\*NULL` right?

Comment: Yes. . . . . . .

Comment: Added [bug report](https://github.com/briandfoy/PerlPowerTools/pull/84)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in `patch`.

```
$self->{...} = \*NULL;
```

should be

```
$self->{...} = *NULL;
```

---

Let's look at these four snippets:

```
my $r;             $s = "abc";    $r = \$s;   say $$r;

my $r; { local $s; $s = "abc";    $r = \$s; } say $$r;

my $r;             *F = \*STDOUT; $r = \*F;   say $r "abc";

my $r; { local *F; *F = \*STDOUT; $r = \*F; } say $r "abc";
```

Given that the first three work, we would expect the fourth to work too, but it doesn't.

We can't really talk in terms of variables and values in Perl. Perl's model is far more complex than C's where a variable is just a name that represents a location. Globs are even more complex because they're both a variable type (`*FOO`) something that can be found in a scalar (`$foo = *FOO;`). The above difference is related to this.

The following does work while still properly localizing `*F`:

```
my $r; { local *F; *F = \*STDOUT; $r = *F; } say $r "abc";
```

`patch` already uses this approach for `*OUT`, but it needs to use it for `*NULL` too. It probably went unnoticed because `*NULL` is used as a sink, and using an undefined handle also acts as a sink (if you disregard the warning and the error returned by `print`).